# jQuery extension: why does it not work on all matching elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an extension going like:

```
$.fn.crazything = function() {
    var self = $(this);
    // do some crazy stuff
    return self;
}
```

And when I call it like:

```
$("div.crazydiv").crazything();
```

It works, but only on the first matching div. If I have more than one div on the page, I need to do:

```
$("div.crazydiv").each(function(i) { $(this).crazything (); });
```

Why is this, and how can I rewrite my extension to work on multiple divs?

Answer (score 6):

Most jQuery plugins use this pattern which handles your crazy stuff:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.crazything = function() {
    // allow setup on jQuery objects that conatin multiple elements:
    return this.each(function() {
      // this function is called once for each element in the jQuery object
      var self = $(this);
      // do some crazy stuff
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Outstanding! Someone needs to come up with a clever name for such a pattern. The "How did I live before jQuery Pattern"?

Comment: Great example.  Please don't omit the "(function($) {" at the beginning and the "})(jQuery);" at the end -- if a plugin doesn't include this pattern, the projects I work on can't use it.

Comment: @Wells: It is nothing special. Inside the function `this` refers to a collection of jQuery objects. So it makes sense that you have to iterate over it...

Comment: The "return this.each(fn(x))" is the critical portion here.  The original code is finding the first div found in all selected divs (as a group), rather than each selected div individually.  The this.each iterates through each selected div.

Comment: I correct, it is not a collection of *jQuery* objects but *DOM* objects.